# A chemistry or physics version of MO

Tags: discussion

Is there a site,  similar to MO, but devoted to chemistry or physics(A discussion site in high level university research )?

Comment: For physics, there is [Physics Overflow](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/).

Comment: For physics there is actually more: http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a [Chemistry Stack Exchange](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/), but I am not familiar with the "level" of its questions and answers.

Comment: @StefanKohl Despite the name, that's not a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It is nowhere stated in the question that the author is looking exclusively for SE sites. PhysicsOverflow was founded outside the SE network in order to have full control over the software and self-governement of our academic community. From a technical point of view, the content of PO is compatible with the SE software.

Comment: @Dilaton And nowhere in my comment did I say that not being a Stack Exchange site made it an invalid suggestion. However, I do think it's reasonable to mention that it's not an SE site, given that it sounds like an SE site and is clearly trying to be similar to SE sites.

Answer (score 6):

There used to be a [Theoretical Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics) Stack Exchange site, "for research level questions in any area of mathematical or theoretical physics." It didn't reach critical mass so closed without leaving beta.

Searching for "chemistry" on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (sorry, I can't find a way of linking to the search results) doesn't show any corresponding proposal for chemistry.

Of course, advanced questions about physics and chemistry are still on-topic at the regular [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) sites (which are analogous to [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), rather than MO).

Comment: Neither Physics SE nor Chemistry SE are (exclusively) research-level academic sites. In particular on Physics SE, the mean level of the content and the style of moderation (strong adherence to the SE philosophy) significantly differs from the nice academic spirit and atmosphere on MO.

Comment: @Dilaton Sure. I said that advanced questions are "still on-topic", implying that other questions are on-topic, too.

Comment: It is probably also worth mentioning that the purpose of Physics SE, which has by the founding members been concepted to be a site for active researchers, academics and (university?) students of physics and astronomy many years ago, is [currenntly getting completely redefined](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9115/2751)...

Comment: Even though SE employees prematurally closed Theoretical Physics SE after not even half a year in public beta (this would no longer happen today, as [SE now better seems to acknowledge the value of smaller high-level communities that naturally have a longer turning time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/184300)), its content is again publicly available in a human readable Q&A format since PhysicsOverflow [took off](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1608/30967).